# Enable the user interaction for a specific SubView in Coverflow mode

Tags: iphone, ios, coverflow

I created a coverflow mode which contains a `UIWebView` for youtube video playing and also i have given tapgesture for the whole view.

Now user interaction is not working on the `UIWebView`.

What i want is to implement a coverflow with tap gesture and video playing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) is the best library so far to show video list in the coverflow View, yes tap gesture is available on tiles.

You'll get detail on GitHub site, go through with the readme file.

But remember one important thing, thumbnails would make much more sense, this will make the application use less processing power and faster performance.

Comment: yea i am using the icarousal and also showing the thumbnail.But after clicking that thumbnail i want it to play the video

Comment: so you want to play video in VideoPlayer or in tile itself